# How to increase the x axis resolution using ggplot in R (from yearly to monthly)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

#This is my code, I need help in improving the x axis resolution that is monthly (an 2017, Feb 2017.....Dec 2020)

```r
ggplot()+
  geom_line(data=IDA_DATA,
            aes(y=final1,x= Date,colour="darkblue"),size=1 )+
  geom_line(data=IDA_DATA,
            aes(y=fpmc2,x= Date,colour="red"),
            size=1) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Y series", labels = c("Adjusted Trend", "Long Term Comp"))+
  theme(legend.position = c(.85, .85))+
  labs(y="PM10 Conc (ug/m3)")
```

[image]

Comment: Use `?scale_x_date`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your Date variable is an actual date type (ie. numeric).

If your data is continuous (measurements on multiple days per month), you can use the `breaks` parameter in `scale_x_continuous()` to specify each break you want. Your breaks will also have to be in date format, not text strings, so you'll need `dmy()` to convert a vector of all the first-day-of-the-month dates. That can be tedious if your data spans many years, but I can't think of how else you can force all the month labels to show up on a continuous axis.

If your data can be summarised as a single x value for each entire month, you can convert the Date into a month-year string or factor variable and use that as a discrete x axis. Discrete axis automatically show all the x values, so you won't have to create all the breaks. This should be relatively easy to achieve.